# Create a branch in the "/feature" folder

Tags: git

I want to create a branch in the "/feature" folder with

```
git checkout -b "/feature/TDK-1692
```

but I got an error:

```
fatal: '/feature/TDK-1692' is not a valid branch name.
```

Comment: Branches are not created in folders. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can not create a branch of only a specific folder in a git repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in [git check-ref-format](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ref-format),

> They cannot begin or end with a slash / or contain multiple consecutive slashes (see the --normalize option below for an exception to this rule)

`/feature/TDK-1692` is not a valid branch name. It would be expanded into `refs/heads//feature/TDK-1692` which violates this rule. `feature/TDK-1692` is okay.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would like to run the command like

```
$ git checkout -b feature/TDK-1692
Switched to a new branch 'feature/TDK-1692'
```